# How to find the base10 of (x:g)?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am at the end of my homework, and a little confused on the right way to go for this algorithm. I need to find the base10 of a number:base that user gives.

Basically what my program does is take user input such as, 407:8 or 1220:5 etc.

What I am trying to output is like this.

```
 INPUT:    407:8 
OUTPUT:    407 base 8 is 263 base 10
```

I was thinking of this long stretched out way of doing it but I am sure there is a way easier way to go about it.

Attached is what i have so far. Thanks for looking!!

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;  //gui stuff
import java.util.Scanner;  // Needed for accepting input
import java.text.*;         //imports methods for text handling
import java.lang.Math.*;    //needed for math stuff*

 public class ProjectOneAndreD      //my class + program name
 {


public static void main(String[] args)  //my main
{
    String input1;      //holds user input
    int val=0, rad=0, check1=0;   //holds integer values user gives
   and check  for : handler
    double answer1=0;   //holds the answer!


        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  
  //creates new scanner class

        do      //will continue to loop if no : inputted
        {
           System.out.println("\t****************************************************");
        System.out.println("\t             Loading Project 1. Enjoy!              ");       //title
        System.out.println("\t****************************************************\n\n");

        input1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("INPUT: ","EXAMPLE:  160:2");  //prompts user with msgbox w/ example
        System.out.println("Program Running...");       //gives user a secondary notice that everything is ok..

        check1=input1.indexOf(":");     //checks input1 for the :

            if(check1==-1)              //if no : do this stuff
            {
                System.out.println("I think you forgot the ':'.");      //let user know they forgot
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You forgot the ':'!!!");   //another alert to user
            }
                else        //otherwise is they remembered :
                {
                    String numbers [] = input1.split(":"); //splits the string at :

                        val = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);   //parses [0] to int and assigns to val
                        rad = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);     //parses [1] to int and assigns to rad
                        //answer1 = ((Math.log(val))/(Math.log(rad)));  //mathematically finds first base then
                        //answer1 = Integer.parseInt(val, rad, 10);

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, val+" base "+rad+" = BLAH base 10.");  //gives user the results
                        System.out.println("Program Terminated...");            //alerts user of program ending
                }

        }while(check1==-1);     //if user forgot : loop 

    }
}
```

Comment: have a look at this so-thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513793

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy, just replace your commented out logic with this:

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; val > Math.pow(rad, i); i++) {
    int digit = (val / (int) Math.pow(10, i)) % 10;
    int digitValue = (int) (digit * Math.pow(rad, i));
    total += digitValue;
}
```

and total has your answer.  The logic is simple - we do some division and then modulus to pull the digit out of val, then multiply by the appropriate radix power and add to the total.

Or, if you want to make it a little more efficient and lose the exponentials:

```
int total = 0;
int digitalPower = 1;
int radPower = 1;
while (val > radPower) {
    int digit = (val / digitalPower) % 10;
    int digitValue = digit * radPower;
    total += digitValue;

    digitalPower *= 10;
    radPower *= rad;
}
```

Comment: Woha, needing three power calls and a modulo (and still some multiplications and additions) to implement something that is basically an addition and multiplication seems a bit on the.. heavy side. Though I assume this gives the OP the possibility to implement this easier.

Comment: Uh, that's still.. more than unnecessarily complex. Before this gets out of hand, the usual solution would be `int total = 0; for (char ch : number.toCharArray()) total = total * base + ch - '0';`. You can use charAt and stuff, but for a twoliner that's simpler. An integer doesn't have a specific base, it just specifies some value, so doing it that way is just strange.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Integer.parseInt(s, radix)`.

```
answer = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0], rad);
```

You parse number in given radix.

Comment: +1 - Nice solution. I wouldn't be surprised if the assignment forbid the use of that method, though. :)

Comment: @Ted I'd hope so, otherwise that'd be quite the useless homework. Everyone should implement converting into and from arbitrary bases and printing those at least once ;)

Comment: Far from useless! Item 47 in Effective Java: "Know and use the libraries!" It's an important point to learn that you do not need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

You only have implemented the user interface. Define a method taking two integers (the base and the number to convert) as argument, and returning the converted number. This is not very difficult. 407:8 means

```
(7 * 8^0) + (0 * 8^1) + (4 * 8^2)
```

You thus have to find a way to extract 7 from 407, then 0, and then 4. The modulo operator can help you here. Or you could treat 407 as a string and extract the characaters one by one and transorm each of them into an int.

Comment: "Or you could treat 407 as a string and extract the characaters one by one and transorm each of them into an int."  that was actually the way I was thinking about doing it, but I didn't wanna go through that unless I had to, answer = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0], rad); seems to work perfectly, ty for assistance tho!!!